# Using Rpi with serial debug ports

Tags: serial

I have a question about providing power to Rpi through serial ports. Please let me know if the following would be possible.

I would connect raspberry pi to beagle bone black through serial debug ports(RX,TX,GND,+5V). It means power would be provided from the beagle bone black to the Rpi and no power cables would be plugged in to Rpi directly. Assuming that a power cable is plugged in the beagle bone black.

And one picamera would be connected to Rpi so that the Rpi captures image and transmit it to the beagle bone black using the serial ports.

My question is this. 
Would it be possible that one provide power to Rpi through the serial debug ports without using any other power cables? Especially, is it okay to use Rpi and picamera with such manner? I mean would there be any problem of lack of power supply?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would not be supplying power via the "serial debug ports".

You would be supplying power via the ground and 5V pins on the expansion header.

Lots of people do that.  Just remember it bypasses any protection the (microUSB) polyfuse may give.

Make sure you don't feed more than 3V3 into the Pi's RXD (or any Pi gpio).

Comment: You mean it's not RX nor Tx but the 5V and GND?

Comment: You can not power the Pi via its gpios.  You can via its power pins. I suggest you post a photo of what you plan to do.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=9665. This is what I want to do to control and take data from picamera

Comment: You can power the Pi from the pins shown (pin 2 is 5V, pin 6 is ground).  You can connect a 3V3 safe serial link to pins 8 and 10.

Comment: Today I tested it with raspberry pi B+ and arduino Uno. I connected 5V port of arduino to Rpi's 5V and also connected the GND ports. But it appeared that Rpi can't boot. The output voltage from the arduino is 4.98V so about 5V. I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: The Pi needs about half an amp to work (and more if there is extra kit connected).  Check the Pi LEDs as you apply power.  What do they do?